# Python: formula to calculate cumulate and monthly value of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have two request for you:
**First one:**
I have the following montly income variable given by the following:

```
total_income={'Revenues': list(100 for m in range(12))}
```

I want to extract (based on the today date) the month income. Ad example with the formula:

```
this_month=datetime.datetime.now()
this_month=now.month
```

I want to extract from total_income the value of this month. Ad example if  `this_month=6` I want to have the income of this month.

**Second one**
Also based on the `this_month` variable I want to get the cumulate sum of all month until it. Ad example if  `this_month=6` I want to have the sum of all income starting from 1 to 6.

Comment: "I want to extract from total_income the value of this month. Ad example if this_month=6 I want to have the income of this month." How would you do it if you just had the list? How would you get the list from the `total_income` dict? Now, just put those two steps together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like that:

```
import datetime

total_income = {'Revenues': [100 for m in range(12)]}

current_month = datetime.date.today().month

current_revenue = total_income['Revenues'][current_month - 1]
cumulative_revenue = sum(total_income['Revenues'][:current_month])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this using the following function:

```
#function definition
def find_income(total_income):
  this_month=datetime.datetime.now().month
  total_income_list = total_income["Revenues"]
  this_month_income = total_income_list[this_month -1]

  sum = 0
  for m in range(this_month):
    sum += total_income_list[m]

  return this_month_income, sum

#Call the function
this_month_income, sum = find_income(total_income)

print(this_month_income) #100
print(sum) #600
```